# consulta Delete C# mysql

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, delete

estoy con un problema, cuando ejecuto este query desde c#, no elimina ningun dato en mi base de datos, pero si lo ejecuto desde el mismo sql de mysql este primero me pregunta si quiero eliminar los datos y luego los elimina, tendré que cambiar alguna configuración en la misma base de datos?

```
            mySql.Open();

            String query = "DELETE FROM `consulta` WHERE `id_consulta` = '" + idconsulta + "');";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, mySql);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Cerrar();
```

Comment: a la base de datos estoy ingresando como root...

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery`  es una función que devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la sentencia, en este caso el `delete`. ¿Qué valor te está devolviendo?

Comment: no me esta devolviendo nada, tampoco me tira un error al momento de ejecutar el query, solo que no afecta la tabla.

Comment: ¿No está devolviendo nada significa que devuelve 0? o ¿qué número devuelve exactamente?